# DB2 trigger syntax

Tags: db2

I an learning to write triggers in DB2.   I need one and only 1 record in mytable have ENABLED_IND= 'Y'.

```
 CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(
     OBJECTID                    BIGINT        GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, NO CACHE, NO CYCLE),     
     MYDATA                         VARCHAR(8)    NOT NULL,
      ....
      ENABLED_IND                 CHAR(1)         NOT NULL
   ) IN "TS_PROF_D" INDEX IN "TS_PROF_IX" ;
```

when ever I insert into mytable I need all existing ENABLED_IND to be set to "N".  I came up with the following, a oracle EE dba says it should work, but does not

```
 CREATE TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.MYTRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE 
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
    BEGIN ATOMIC
    UPDATE MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE SET ENABLED_IND = 'N';
   END
```

All db2 is telling me "illegal character"  We don't see an illegal character.  The web examples of db2 triggers are very confusing.

Comment: Have you set youir statement termination character to something <> ";"? As ";" is used inside the trigger you have to define a different one for the create trigger statement.

Comment: When you fix your terminator issue, check your expectations.  The trigger won't fire for UPDATE statements (if the table gets updated) although you can add a before update trigger, and triggers won't fire for LOAD. Also check how that single row will get ENABLED_IND set to 'Y' if before-insert/update triggers are active.